# What digital illustrated dictionaries are available?

Tags: dictionary, software

What dictionaries are available that contain separate illustrations for most of the terms? I would prefer something in online or digital format.

Answer (score 1):

I found two but they are to be purchased and not free.

1. [McGraw-Hill's Chinese Illustrated Dictionary](http://www.mcgrawhill.ca/professional/products/9780071615907/mcgraw-hill%27s+chinese+illustrated+dictionary/): 1,500 Essential Words in Chinese Script and Pinyin lay the foundation of your language learning;
2. [Illustrated Chinese-English Dictionary](http://www.liveabc.com/english/chinese_info.asp?b_category=Books&issn=978-1-935181-94-1&items).

Comment: The total number of words in both are very low. Are there any resources with more words?

Answer (score 0):

nciku.com has images for many of its entries (not the majority by any means, but most common nouns have images). There's also a 'theme words' section where all of the entries have images, categorised by subject (e.g. food, sports, clothing etc)

Answer (score 0):

The **Yale Picture Dictionary** has a [version for Chinese](http://classes.yale.edu/chns130/Dictionary/index.html).  This is a small dictionary for learners.  It has basic words organized into categories (such as colours, animals, etc.).  This is a dictionary to find new words to learn, not a dictionary to look up things in.

I have not used the Chinese version much (yet!), but I did use the Greek version extensively in the past and found it quite useful as a beginner.  It is designed in a way so you can also use it in a similar way to flashcards ("do I remember what to call this thing in this picture")?

---

There is a similar illustrated vocabulary collection at **[LanguageGuide.org](http://www.languageguide.org/mandarin/vocabulary/)**, just suggested to me by a friend.  I have not used this (yet).

Comment: The Yale Picture Dictionary link is broken.